# Nginx rewrite POST as GET, and redirect

Tags: php, post, nginx, get, url-rewriting

Is it possible for a `POST` request to `http://me.com`

to be converted to a `GET` request such as `http://me.com/api.php?some_static_param=yippee;<rest of post data as get request>` using Nginx?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a scripting language such as Lua or Perl but as these are relatively obscure and Lua need to be installed and a module compiled, why not just do it using the scripting language you already have in place and probably quite familiar with ... PHP?.

Setup your index file to access the [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) array if it exists, build the request string and send a [location header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to redirect the user.